# Broken Drywall Corner in Shower

Tags: patching-drywall

I had someone replace my bathroom ceiling, and I was just sanding and painting.  I found that the corner of the drywall is broken off & there is also another gap that seems a bit big for caulking.  I think I can maybe just add a little compound on gap, but I'm not sure how to fix the corner given I can't put anything on the shower tile.  Any suggestions (other than having to schedule a guy to come back)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. It's not clear what I'm looking at. Is that the wall-ceiling junction, or is there a tub in the photo?

Answer (score 2):

I added compound in the gap and that seems OK.  I folded up some paper drywall tape into the corner to fill the depth, and then put compound on that too.  Both had some mesh tape in there so I think it will be OK.  Thanks to anyone who has been giving this thought!

Comment: Normally you'd fill void with compound to make it more solid, but with the mesh tape it should be ok.

Comment: I'd have called the guy back as much as I hate mudding drywall, but I think you did well.